# Assigning to variables inside Run Keyword If

Tags: robotframework

```
\   Run Keyword If    ${i} == 7    log to console     Testing Variant 1
\   ${is visible}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   (//li[@class='_8HqL0'])[${i}]
\   Run Keyword If    ${is visible}  Run keywords
\   ...  Scroll Element Into View    (//li[@class='_8HqL0'])[${i}]
\   ...   AND     Click Element     (//li[@class='_8HqL0'])[${i}]
\   ...   AND     sleep  2s
\   ...    set variable   ${Ad_Path}  Get Text  //*[@class='rui-3blDo _1Uh38 _27AdP']
\   ...   AND     log to console    ${Ad_Path}
```

Hi i want to use the GET TEXT activity inside a IF block in FOR but its giving an error stating keyword name cannot be empty help

Comment: It seems to me that this code example is incomplete as it's missing the `FOR` loop expression you refer to. Can you also explain why you use the `Run Keywords` approach instead of creating a custom keyword and calling that?

Comment: @A.Kootstra i am new to robot framework and i have no clue how to run multiple statements in IF block . The basic idea is that using the GET TEXT i want to fetch the data using xpath. There are 12 or 13 values that i need to extract from OLX website. I have a FOR loop to iterate over the ads and to extract details from them. Based on a condition i want to use GET TEXT in a IF block any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a construct `${variable}=     Returned Value From Keyword` inside a `Run Keyword`/`Run Keyword If` because the latter expects everything passed to it to be a *keyword* - and it considers `${variable}` also to be one.

There is one "workaround" - `Run Keyword If` propagates back up the last returned value in its keyword, and that can be set to a variable. E.g. you can do this:

```
${variable}=     Run Keyword If    ${condition}    Returned Value From Keyword    ELSE    Set Variable    other value
```

Mind the `ELSE` in this construct - without it, if the condition is false the variable will be undefined - will be left with a value `None` (the data type).

Naturally, if the `Run Keyword If` has more than one steps (like your console logs) you'll have to break it up - a block that "does things", and another (or others) that "assigns values".

I've typed "workaround" in quotes because it isn't really such - it's the way the keyword is designed to be used.